# Help in solve the matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have written the following code. I have two main problems. The first is how to solve the matrix for different Omega, and the second is that if I put letters instead of numbers for k or m, the values will not add up(plus).

```
Subscript[k, 1] = K;
Subscript[k, 2] = K;
Subscript[k, 3] = K;
Subscript[m, 1] =M;
Subscript[m, 2] = 2*M;
Subscript[m, 3] = 2*M;
n = 3;
Format[m[n_]] := Subscript[m, n];
mv = Array[m, n];
(mm = (mv) IdentityMatrix[n]) // MatrixForm
Format[k[n_]] := Subscript[k, n];
kv = Array[k, n];
(kk = (kv + Join[Rest[kv], {0}]) IdentityMatrix[n] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], 1] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], -1]) // MatrixForm
(Omega = Solve[Det[kk - mm*\[Omega]] == 0, \[Omega]]) // N
(Time = 2 Pi/Sqrt[Omega] // RootReduce) // N
(mA = kk - mm*Omega[[i]] // RootReduce);
mC = {0, 0};
mX = Array[\[Phi], 2];
eqn = mA.mX == mC;
sol = Solve[eqn, mX]
(sol = (SolveAlways[eqn, mX])) // N
```

And how to get the answer in the form of a matrix as shown below

```
n = 3
Table[Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}];
MatrixForm[%]
```

I thought maybe it would help, the top matrix is a modal matrix for structural modes
[image]

In the book it is mentioned that for each Omega there is a Phi vector which is known as the special vector or the characteristic vector, also elsewhere the unit value is considered for the component related to the first class.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

k[1] = 4000;
k[2] = 4000;
k[3] = 5000;
m[1] = 10;
m[2] = 2;
m[3] = 5;
n = 3;

mv = m /@ Range[n];
mm = (mv) IdentityMatrix[n];
kv = k /@ Range[n];

(kk = (kv + Join[Rest[kv], {0}]) IdentityMatrix[n] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], 1] + DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], -1]);

(Omega = ω /. Solve[Det[kk - mm*ω] == 0, ω]) // N

(* {177.181, 857.532, 5265.29} *)

(Time = 2 Pi/Sqrt[Omega] // RootReduce) // N

(* {0.472032, 0.214563, 0.0865902} *)

(mA = Table[kk - mm*Omega[[i]], {i, n}] // RootReduce);

mC = ConstantArray[0, n];

Format[ϕ[n_]] := Subscript[ϕ, n];

mX = Array[ϕ, n];

eqns = Table[mA[[i]].mX == mC, {i, n}];

(sol = Solve[#, mX] & /@ eqns // RootReduce // Quiet) /. x_Root :> N[x]
```

[image]

The solution gives  `ϕ[2]` and `ϕ[3]` in terms of `ϕ[1]`. If instead you want `ϕ[1]` and `ϕ[2]` in terms of `ϕ[3]`,

```
(sol2 = Solve[#, Most@mX, MaxExtraConditions -> All] & /@ eqns // RootReduce //
     Quiet) /. x_Root :> N[x]
```

[image]

I do not understand the relation of the results to the pictures that you show.

**EDIT:** Using symbolic values

```
Clear["Global`*"]

k[1] = K;
k[2] = K;
k[3] = K;
m[1] = M;
m[2] = 2*M;
m[3] = 2*M;
n = 3;

mv = Array[m, n];
(mm = (mv) IdentityMatrix[n]) // MatrixForm;

kv = Array[k, n];
(kk = (kv + Join[Rest[kv], {0}]) IdentityMatrix[n] + 
     DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], 1] + DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], -1]) // 
  MatrixForm;

(Omega = ω /. Solve[Det[kk - mm*ω] == 0, ω])

(* {K/M, (5 K - Sqrt[21] K)/(4 M), (5 K + Sqrt[21] K)/(4 M)} *)

Time = 2 Pi/Sqrt[Omega];

mA = Table[kk - mm*Omega[[i]], {i, n}];

mC = ConstantArray[0, n];

Format[ϕ[m_, n_]] := Subscript[ϕ, m, n]

mX = Array[ϕ, {n, n}];

eqn = Table[mA[[i]].mX[[i]] == mC, {i, n}];

sol = Table[Solve[eqn[[i]], mX[[i]]], {i, n}] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Your comment is unclear. First, do not set `k[2] = k` Since `k` is being used as an indexed variable; do not also try to use it as a separate variable. At best it is confusing. Second, what "answer" are you talking about? In any event, anywhere `k[1] + k[2]` occurs it would be `K + k` since `K` and `k` are distinct. As I said before, if you are having a problem with your code show the actual code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for providing the solution, and then I have to say that I realized my mistake and for this reason I deleted the comment, I put lowercase(k) letters instead of uppercase(K),And now the problem is solved but...

Comment: To solve the problem Phi must be like this `{{\[Phi][1, 1], \[Phi][1, 2], \[Phi][1, 3]}, {\[Phi][2, 1], \[Phi][2, 
   2], \[Phi][2, 3]}, {\[Phi][3, 1], \[Phi][3, 2], \[Phi][3, 3]}}` but in your code is  `{Subscript[\[Phi], 1], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]}`

Comment: How can I solve the equation if I assume I have several answers, for example [Phi][3,1 ]=1 , [Phi][3, 2]=1 , [Phi][3, 3]=1

Comment: The question in your comment makes no sense to me. The `phi` for a given `omega` have a set relationship. They cannot all be arbitrarily set. At most one of the three. To ask a question show what you have tried and state where you are having a problem.

Comment: The code you worked on and wrote down gives the value of phi in terms of other phi, I asked how I can have the rest of the phi in numbers (numerically) by giving values to phi, I hope I can achieve my point

Comment: `sol /. {\[Phi][1, 1] -> 1, \[Phi][2, 1] -> 1, \[Phi][3, 1] -> 1}` Note that as previously stated, only one of the `phi` for an `omega` can be assigned a value.